# Extract upto N digits from a pandas string column not preceded or succeeded by any other digits

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

python python-3.x pandas
I have bit of headache with this mixed String data. I have a data with mixed alphanumeric, text, numeric characters and long integer in the data.

Can you please guide me in solving my issue?

Here logic is that, in this mixed string, following logic needs to be applied,

If its alphanumeric character like 1-HRCC, 455-HRCC, it should pick only the numeric values from it (it should only limit to <=999).
if only numbers are present it should replicate the same number but only if the numbers are <=999. for e.g. 45,90, 888,999 to give output of the same number, but if number is >999 it should output those values as 1.
if any blanks are present it should keep the same as blank.
if any text characters like abc,def, ghi, pillar mill etc should output as 1.
Any numbers 123 678984 or alphanumeric with space(ahd 233 xyz) should also output as 1.
I have defined the below function,as i am still in learning phase not sure how to achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'Callback':['1-HRCC','Pilar Mill',' ','abc',' ','Kar.J.Kueger@xxx.com','xyz','mc','2-   HRCC','Regional','15','10','2','99-HRCC','43- HRCC','675','888','4-   HRCC','31318697418','30-HRCC','25-HRCC','30-HRCC']})
```

```
def reg_clean(s):
    if isinstance(s,str) and s[:0].isdigit():
        return int(''.join(ele for ele in s if ele.isdigit()))
    elif isinstance(s,str) and s=="":
            return ""
#    elif  s[:1].isdigit():?
#            return s
    else:
        return 1
df['Callback1']= df['Callback'].map(reg_clean)
```

Mixed_String(Input),Output

```
1-HRCC,1
Pilar Mill,1
abc,1
Kar.J.Kueger@xxx.com,1
xyz,1
mc,1
2-HRCC,2
Regional,1
,
15,15
10,10
2,2
99-HRCC,99
,
43-HRCC,43
675,675
888,888
4-HRCC,4
31318697418,1
30-HRCC,30
25-HRCC,25
30-HRCC,30
```

here output is separated using a comma(,). Currently everything is resulting to 1.

Comment: Please show your expected output (at least for the first 5-10 rows).

Comment: Hey, expected output I have mentioned above itself in the very end..

Comment: Thank you so much,Yes it served the purpose almost. I believe you just missed this line. " if any blanks are present it should keep the same as blank. if any text characters like abc,def, ghi, pillar mill etc should output as 1." ... Currently even blanks are converting to 1. Which should keep the value to blank only.

Comment: issue is sorted instead of using pd.numeric i just replaced blanks with 1 and Nan with blanks. df['ext'] = df['ext'].replace("",1)
df['ext'] = df['ext'].replace('NaN',"")

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex like `(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})(?!\d)` to match any 3 digit chunk not enclosed with digits. First, check if a string is not blank, if it is, the result should be an empty string. Else, grab the regex match value or `1` if there was no match:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

regex = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})(?!\d)')
def reg_clean(s):
    if not s.strip(): # if strins is not blank
        return ""     # Return empty
    else:
        m = regex.search(s)       # If there is a regex match
        if m:
            return int(m.group()) # return the match value
        else:
            return 1              # Else, return 1

df=pd.DataFrame({'Callback':['1-HRCC','Pilar Mill',' ','abc',' ','Kar.J.Kueger@xxx.com','xyz','mc','2-   HRCC','Regional','15','10','2','99-HRCC','43- HRCC','675','888','4-   HRCC','31318697418','30-HRCC','25-HRCC','30-HRCC']})
df['ext'] = df['Callback'].apply(reg_clean)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                Callback  ext
0                 1-HRCC    1
1             Pilar Mill    1
2                            
3                    abc    1
4                            
5   Kar.J.Kueger@xxx.com    1
6                    xyz    1
7                     mc    1
8              2-   HRCC    2
9               Regional    1
10                    15   15
11                    10   10
12                     2    2
13               99-HRCC   99
14              43- HRCC   43
15                   675  675
16                   888  888
17             4-   HRCC    4
18           31318697418    1
19               30-HRCC   30
20               25-HRCC   25
21               30-HRCC   30
```